# Multiple Regression Quadratic Assignment Procedure

Tags: multiple-regression, references

Can you advice a paper or a book about ''Multiple Regression Quadratic Assignment Procedure'? I need information about the essentials and the assumptions of the procedure.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Dekker, D., Krackhardt, D., & Snijders, T. A. B. (2007). Sensitivity of MRQAP tests to collinearity and autocorrelation conditions. Psychometrika, 72(4), 563–581. https://doi.org/10.1007/s11336-007-9016-1

Lindgren, K. O. (2010). Dyadic regression in the presence of heteroscedasticity-An assessment of alternative approaches. Social Networks, 32(4), 279–289. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.socnet.2010.04.002

In the first article they propose the double semi-partialization method to extend the QAP (quadratic assignment procedures) correlations to multiple regression. This method performs permutations of the residuals to compare an observed statistic with the values obtained after the re-labeling of the data.

In the second, he proposes to use robust errors to deal with heteroskedasticity conditions. There is no method of detecting heteroscedasticity, so Lindgren proposes using alternative methods. In my experience, there are very few differences between the two, probably due to the low heteroscedasticity of the data.

No independence of observations is required

Comment: (+1) But, please, put some text in for the citations to reference.